# How to append an object to json variable in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to store objects to a json variable which is already defined.

This is for angular 6

```
 Data: [{}]; //json variable
let tempData={
      "File_Name" : "ABC",
          "Processed_By" : "ABC",
          "Start_Date": "ABC",
          "End_Date": "ABC",
          "No_Of_Request": "ABC",
          "Planned_Effort": "ABC",
          "Actual_Effort": "ABC"
    } //Object

    this.Data.push(tempData); //adding the object to json variable
```

I except the object to be appended with the json variable.

Comment: var json = {Data : []};
.....
this.json.Data.push(tempData);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your `Data` variable.

```js
Data = []; //json variable
let tempData={
      "File_Name" : "ABC",
          "Processed_By" : "ABC",
          "Start_Date": "ABC",
          "End_Date": "ABC",
          "No_Of_Request": "ABC",
          "Planned_Effort": "ABC",
          "Actual_Effort": "ABC"
    } //Object

    this.Data.push(tempData); //adding the object to json variable
    
    console.log(this.Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Data: [{}];
```

to

```
let data:[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Data = []; //json variable
let tempData={
      "File_Name" : "ABC",
          "Processed_By" : "ABC",
          "Start_Date": "ABC",
          "End_Date": "ABC",
          "No_Of_Request": "ABC",
          "Planned_Effort": "ABC",
          "Actual_Effort": "ABC"
    } //Object

    this.Data.push(tempData); 
console.log(this.Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now below code works.

```
Data: [{}]; //json variable
      tempData={
      "File_Name" : "ABC",
          "Processed_By" : "ABC",
          "Start_Date": "ABC",
          "End_Date": "ABC",
          "No_Of_Request": "ABC",
              "Planned_Effort": "ABC",
              "Actual_Effort": "ABC"
        }//Object

 ngOnInit() {         
    this.Data.push(this.tempData); //adding the object to json variable
    console.log(this.Data)
   }
```